# ¿Cómo expandir un Text Area verticalmente al arrastrar un div en HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Asi como el textarea sobre el que se publica en esta plataforma que en la parte inferior tiene un div del cual se puede modificar el alto del textarea..

Intente con esto y a pesar de que si se expande, se mueve de manera descontrolada:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var yInicial = 0;
        var presionar = false;

        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#expandir').mousedown(function(event) {
                yInicial = event.clientY;
                presionar = true;
            });

            $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
                if(presionar){
                    var altoAgregado = event.clientY - yInicial;
                    $('#txtContenido').height($('#txtContenido').height() + altoAgregado);
                }
            });

            $(document).mouseup(function(event) {
                presionar = false;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Este es el codigo que utilizo. el id expandir es el div y el id txtContenido es el TextArea.

Como se muestra en el codigo, estoy utilizando JQuery!

Comment: ¿Por qué desactivar el comportamiento redimensionable natural de `textarea` para crearlo tú? ¿Solo por curiosidad? ¿Das soporte para navegadores muy viejos?

Comment: Lo que pasa es que el TextArea lo tenia dentro de un div y al expandirlo el div contenedor no lo hacia, dando como resultado que el textarea se colocara encima de los componentes ubicados debajo del contenedor al expandirlo.

Comment: Hmm, era que pongas tu estructura HTML y tu código CSS de ella. Mira [este fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vgLpw9nb/1/), funciona como se espera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te faltaba solo un detalle, lo que pasa es que estabas tratando de sumarle lo que ha recorrido el mouse `yInicial - event.clientY` al tamaño anterior, entonces supongamos tu textarea tiene de altura 50px y bajas 1px, al hacer la suma, tu textarea crece a 51px, luego tu sigues arrastrando un 1px hacia abajo, quiere decir  que has recorrido 2px y lo sumas al tamaño anterior 51px sería 53px, lo cual está mal por que solo has recorrido 2px, esto sigue creciendo algebraicamente.

Lo que hice fue agregar una variable para almacenar el tamaño inicial, cosa que puedes modificar el tamaño libremente sin perder el tamaño incial.

```js
var yInicial = 0;
var presionar = false;
var heightInicial = 0;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#expandir').mousedown(function(event) {
    yInicial = event.clientY;
    presionar = true;
    heightInicial = $('#txtContenido').height();
  });

  $(document).mousemove(function(event) {
    if (presionar) {
      var altoAgregado = event.clientY - yInicial;
      $('#txtContenido').height(heightInicial + altoAgregado);
    }
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function(event) {
    presionar = false;
  });
});
```

```css
#txtContenido {
  width: 100%;
  resize: none;
  border: #aaa solid 1px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#expandir {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(#ccc, #ddd);
  border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
  color: #aaa;
  text-align: center;
  height: 10px;
  cursor: ns-resize;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<textarea id="txtContenido"></textarea>
<div id="expandir"></div>
```

> Te recomiendo que en vez de guardar esos datos como variables, los guardes como atributos del textarea cosa que tu código sería más genérico.

Comment: Hey gracias, ya funciona perfectamente,  se me escapo ese detalle! Saludos!